# LEFT JOIN a subconsulta devuelve datos duplicados

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola a todos tengo unos problemas de data duplicada en mi consulta:

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  FechaCorte, KeyAfiliado, MAX(FechaPerdido)FechaPerdido 
FROM CorteAfiliado
                    WHERE FechaPerdido IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY FechaCorte,KeyAfiliado
```

Que devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, lo que yo necesito es hacer un SELECT a la misma tabla pero sin agrupar, pero que me devuelva el campo **FechaPerdido** de la anterior consulta para todas las FechaCorte menores a esta.

Este sería el resultado que quiero obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT A.FechaCorte,A.KeyAfiliado, Z.FechaPerdido FROM CorteAfiliado A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  FechaCorte, KeyAfiliado, MAX(FechaPerdido)FechaPerdido 
FROM CorteAfiliado
                    WHERE FechaPerdido IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY FechaCorte,KeyAfiliado)Z
                ON A.KeyAfiliado = Z.KeyAfiliado AND 
A.FechaCorte>=Z.FechaPerdido
WHERE A.FECHACORTE BETWEEN '2017-07-04' AND '2019-10-23'
ORDER BY A.FECHACORTE
```

Pero obtengo lo siguiente (VALORES DUPLICADOS):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que con lo siguiente podrás solucionar el problema, o al menos darte otra posible idea :)

```
SELECT A.FechaCorte,A.KeyAfiliado, (SELECT MAX(FechaPerdido) FechaPerdido FROM CorteAfiliado Z WHERE FechaPerdido IS NOT NULL AND A.KeyAfiliado = Z.KeyAfiliado AND A.FechaCorte>=Z.FechaPerdido) AS FechaPerdido
FROM CorteAfiliado A
WHERE A.FECHACORTE BETWEEN '2017-07-04' AND '2019-10-23'
ORDER BY A.FECHACORTE
```

Espero te ayude, un saludo!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén, era lo que buscaba.

Comment: Genial, me alegra que te haya ayudado  :)